# Are the following probabilities independent?

Tags: probability, simulation, independence, biostatistics

I am building an agent-based SIR model (model in which an infection spreads through a population with susceptible, infected, recovered, and deceased people) and I am running into a bit of a problem. When people are infected, they have a certain probability to die in a given discrete time period, say 0.005 * 7 / 18. They also have a probability to recover, say 0.995 * 7 / 18. In my model, the former is heterogeneous, but that is not relevant for my problem here.

When I coded this is into Python, I initially looped over all agents in the model and gave them a 0.995 * 7 / 18 probability to recover. Then I looped over all infected agents again, giving them a 0.005 * 7 / 18 probability to die. After a bit, I realized this was wrong, since by the time I use the loop that kills agents, the pool of infected agents has shrunk due to recovery.

My solution was as follows. For each agent, I take two random rolls from a uniform (0,1) distribution. If the first roll is below 0.995 * 7 / 18, but the second is above 0.005 * 7 / 18, the agent recovers. If the first roll is above 0.995 * 7 / 18, but the second is below 0.005 * 7 / 18, the agent dies. If both are above their threshold, the agent remains infected. If both are  below their threshold, the agent would both die and recover, so I take two new random rolls until I get one the three former situations.

The thing is, after making this change to my program, the number of deceased people at the end declined by factor 4, which seems like a lot, especially since I expected the number of deceased people to increase (since initially the pool of infected people which could die was too small).

My question is whether the way I implemented these rolls is statistically sound, or if there are problems with independence that distort the implemented probabilities to die/recover.

Comment: I think the question here is more like: What do you want? What is wrong with the following approach? If somebody is infected at a certain time t there are multiple possibilities what happens to that person in the transition from t to t+1: stay infected (and nothing happens), recover and die. Those three options must add up to one (if they don't then your forgot to tell us something about your model). Just sample one action from a discrete distributions with these probabilities and apply the action sampled to that agent.

Comment: I hadn't thought about it that way. I am still not really sure of my current approach works or not, but I do have a new approach in mind that I am quite sure should work. Thanks a lot.